# Need to send Json to JMS using Apache Camel Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, jms

I am using spring-boot for Apache Camel and I am able to send messages from one queue to another queue.

blow is the code

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class JmsRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JmsRoute.class);

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("{{inbound.endpoint}}")
                .transacted()
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, log, "Recived Message")
                .process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        Student student = new Student();
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        String json = gson.toJson(student);
                        log.info("Exchange: {}", exchange.getMessage().getBody());
                        log.info("**********:{}", exchange.getMessage());
                    }
                })
                .loop()
                .simple("{{outbound.loop.count}}")
                .to("{{outbound.endpoint}}")
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, log, "Message Sent")
                .end();
    }
}
```

I need to send to convert Object to JSON(Which I can convert using Gson) and then send it over the queue.

I am new to Camel and tried to find the solution for this over the internet but couldn't get any help.

Can anyone please help here ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the json to the exchange body.

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        Student student = new Student();
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        String json = gson.toJson(student);
                        exchange.getIn().setBody(json); //processor does not do this automatically
                        log.info("Exchange: {}", exchange.getMessage().getBody());
                        log.info("**********:{}", exchange.getMessage());
                    }
```

I recommend checking out the new documentation pages for apache camel. They are great. Especially if you are just starting to use the framework. See https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/getting-started.html